# How to Insert Work Item in a LiveDoc using web-service client api in Polarion?

Tags: api, web-services, requirements, siemens, polarion

I have a question about the Polarion SDK API. I am trying to insert WorkItems in a LiveDoc using webservices api. The webservics have apis for creating a workitem within the doc/module or move item but there is no api for just inserting the existing workItem into the Live/doc/module. Is there any work around? Again, the question is about doing this task using webService client(which every user has access to) and not using servlet side IWorkItem interface.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The question is about a missing or non-existing api call, thus providing a code example is....a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

In the API you find the method:

```
moveWorkItemToDocument
```

The Documentation states:

> Moves a Work Item to a specific position in a Document. If the Work
> Item is not yet inside the Document it will be moved into the
> Document. Modules are also supported.
>
> @param **workItemURI** The URI of
> the Work Item to be moved.
>
> @param **documentURI** The URI of the Document.
>
> @param **parentWorkItemURI** The URI of the parent Work Item or {@code
> null} to insert it as the root.
>
> @param **position** The desired position in the list of children or a value < 0 to insert the Work Item at the end. (If the old and new parent are the same, then the moved Work Item is not counted.)
>
> @param **retainDocumentFlow** {@code true} to retain the
> position of the moved Work Item in the document flow, even if it means
> changing the parent. {@code false} to keep the desired parent, even if
> it means moving the Work Item to a different position.
>
> @since 3.7.0